# Python print every unique combination of list items

Tags: python, scipy

What is the cleanest (most "pythonic") way of printing every unique combination of three items in the following list?

```
strats = ["1","2","3","4"]
```

The solution needs to avoid duplicates:

```
1 and 1 and 1 No (not unique)
1 and 1 and 2 No (not unique)
1 and 1 and 3 No (not unique)
...
1 and 2 and 3 Yes
1 and 2 and 4 Yes
1 and 3 and 1 No (not unique)
1 and 3 and 2 No (occurred previously)
...
```

I am using numbers here just for clarity, the actual project involve text strings and there are 24 of them, but the same logic should apply.

Here is my first attempt:

```
strats = ["1","2","3","4"]

for a in strats:
    for b in strats:
        for c in strats:
            if a != b and a != c and b!=c:
                print(a+" and "+b+" and "+c)
```

The problem with the output is that it contains duplicates:

```
1 and 2 and 3 Fine
1 and 2 and 4 Fine
1 and 3 and 2 Duplicate
1 and 3 and 4 Fine
1 and 4 and 2 Duplicate
1 and 4 and 3 Duplicate
...
```

Comment: `itertools.combinations`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has built-in support for permutations and combinations.  This will print out all the unique sets of 3 from a universe of N items:

```
import itertools
for nxt in itertools.combinations(strats, 3):
   print(nxt)
```

There are 2,024 ways of taking 3 items from a population of 24.

Comment: Very cool, I will research that, but the code above produces duplicates.

Comment: ('1', '2', '3')
('1', '2', '4')
('1', '3', '2')
('1', '3', '4')

Comment: Yes, you need combinations, not permutations.